# WP/Woo send email to custom meta recipient while post is being published

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to send an email after a new woo product is published. The recipient email is being added inside a custom meta in the product. Below is what I have in my functions.php so far. If I add a manual email in the function it works but unfortunately I can't get the post meta. Is this because the function is being triggered while the product is being/not yet saved? How can I achieve this?

```
function set_mail_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
function notify_owner($post_id) {
    if ( get_post_type($post_id) == 'product' ) {
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $owner_email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_custom_meta_here', true);
        $subject = "Hello";
        $message = "<p>Message goes here.</p>";
        add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type');
        wp_mail($owner_email, $subject, $message);
        remove_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type');
    }
}
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('private_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('auto-draft_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
```

I also tried to add/change the following no luck:

```
global $post;
$owner_email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_meta_here', true);
$owner_email = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_meta_here', true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition post status action hook used for your callback function uses `$post` as a `WP_post` object, but you are using `$post_id` which is wrong. So for your case you could use the following options:

**1.** Implement the [`{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/old_status_to_new_status/) action hook.

```php
function set_mail_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
function notify_owner($post) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        $owner_email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_meta_here', true);
        $subject = "Hello";
        $message = "<p>Message goes here.</p>";
        add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type');
        wp_mail($owner_email, $subject, $message);
        remove_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type');
    }
}
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('private_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
add_action('auto-draft_to_publish', 'notify_owner');
```

**2.** Implement the [`{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/) action hook

```php
function set_mail_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
function notify_owner($post) {
    $owner_email = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_meta_here', true);
    $subject = "Hello";
    $message = "<p>Message goes here.</p>";
    add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type');
    wp_mail($owner_email, $subject, $message);
    remove_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_mail_html_content_type');
}
add_action('publish_product', 'notify_owner');
```